# code::blocks não copilano Ubuntu 20.04.2?

Tags: c, compiladores, codeblocks

Uso Ubuntu 20.04.2 e sempre usei o Visual Studio Code para programar. Entretanto, na linguagem c, preciso usar a biblioteca <allegro.h>, e preciso usar então o code::blocks. Entretanto, não consigo compilar nenhum arquivo no code::blocks.

Verifiquei, e tenho o gcc e g++ no computador, tentei instalar pelo comando

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks g++
```

e também tentei verificar se a pasta que o programa pega o compilador está correto, pelo botão settings > compiler > toolchain executables (realmente tive que arrumar essa etapa, coloquei na pasta bin que tem os arquivos codeblocks, gcc e g++)

[image: Foto 1]

Entretanto, ainda não consigo compilar. A janela do terminal abre, mas não acontece nada, e o programa tb não cria o arquivo executável.

[image: Figura 2]

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: Não gerou um executável na sua área de trabalho?

Comment: Não. Fica apenas nisso. O mesmo arquivo, se fizer direto no terminal com `gcc teste1.c -o teste1` dá certo.